# Connect to sub-domain on remote desktop

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

I've got a django project augmented with tenants on remote PC and is run in Docker container and Nginx container serves to it. I've created some clients called `test` and `radar` , so on remote desktop I can connect to them through `test.localhost` and `radar.localhost`, but I can't do the same thing from my PC, e.g. typing in `radar` (radar is an alias of remote desktop in my PC's `/etc/hosts` file) from my machine raises 404 error - no such tenants. But trying to connect with `test.radar` it just can't find anything. So, basically what do I need is when accessing just `radar` from my PC, I want remote desktop response me just like it does when it request `test.localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the truth is Chrome doesn't recognize `test.localhost` which is rewritten in my /etc/hosts file. As I understood, Chrome treats all URLs where localhost part is surrounded with dots as regular localhost URL. I could access remote desktop with Firefox. Kinda strange I'd say.